# Сменить URL

Tags: php

привет...
Как динамически формировать URL средствами PHP(без js!!)?

Хочу на подобии способа

```
function hashq(){
    $range='';
    for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
        $range.=  range('a', 'z')[rand(0,20)];

    }

    return substr(crypt($range),12,10);
}
echo '<a href="omg.php?hashmy='.hashq().'">Link<a>';
```

Только при прямом переходе на **omg.php** чтобы добавилась
http://localhost/omg.php?hashmy=dt.ghPgxJ1  при чем рандомная....
Знаю вариант только через

```
header('Location:')
```

Других нету?

Comment: а чем вас не устраивает способ с header ? есть ещё [`<meta http-equiv="refresh" ...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta)

Comment: а при header разве сохраняются POST данные?

Comment: я че-то не вижу в вопросе ничего про POST. ответом вам будет - получили POST - положите его в сессию и отметьте там-же что вы сделали редирект и надо этот POST достать при первом-же удобном случае.

Comment: Cпасибо за ценный коментарий....Я думал $_SERVER как-то сдесь поможет...

Comment: а чем он поможет ? то что вы хотите делается либо через js(хотя я вот сомневаюсь, что js почему-то сможет переслать POST на другую форму без ajax) либо вот как я в ответе написал - подделкой $_POST (имейте ввиду, file upload так нельзя подделывать, будет бяка, на самом деле в сессию конечно лучше складывать обработанные данные, файлик куда нить записывать если пришел и прочее)

Comment: @zloctb см апдейт

Comment: Довольный ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я че-то не вижу в вопросе ничего про POST. ответом вам будет - получили POST - положите его в сессию и отметьте там-же что вы сделали редирект и надо этот POST достать при первом-же удобном случае. можно даже так (просто пример поясняющий идею)

```
session_start();
$_POST=count($_POST)?$_POST:get_lastpost();
if (rand(1,10)==5) { set_lastpost(); header('Location:'); }
if ($_POST) print_r($_POST);

function get_lastpost() {
   if (isset($_SESSION['LastPost']) {
      $lastPost=$_SESSION['LastPost'];
      unset($_SESSION['LastPost']);
      return $lastPost;
   }
   return false; //хотя конечно это плохо, просто для примера
}

function set_lastpost() {
    $_SESSION['LastPost']=$_POST;
}
```

я вас по итогу немного обманул вы можете ещё так сделать:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect");
header("Location: newurl.php");
```

но если дело происходит на одном сервере, то лучше в сессию записывать.
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-21#page-56